# Sort lines of JSON in a file

Tags: json, perl, sorting

I am parsing several log lines and converting each one into a JSON.  After that I append this JSON into a file

```
my %logContent = (
  sequence_number => 0001,
  line => "2015-11-27T14:32+05:00 abc.com ssh[2321] fjdklsfjlsdlfksd",
  line_number => 689,
);
open (FILE, ">>", "somefile") or die "Cannot open file for append!";
print FILE encode_json \%logContent;
```

So now I have a file that contains several lines of JSON like such:

```
{sequence_number: 0001, line: gibberish, ...}
{sequence_number: 0003, line: gibberish, ...}
{sequence_number: 0002, line: gibberish, ...}
```

I'd like to know the easiest way for me to sort the lines of JSON based on the value of the "sequence_number".  In other words, I'd like the final output to be something like:

```
{sequence_number: 0001, line: gibberish, ...}
{sequence_number: 0002, line: gibberish, ...}
{sequence_number: 0003, line: gibberish, ...}
```

I also have another question: Do you guys/gals think that it would be easier to insert (not append) a new line of JSON into the file in the correct line making the final file sorted by default?  How would I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's horrible. A single file shouldn't contain multiple JSON data structures without a simple way to delimit them. Who designed this? Are you stuck with it, or can you propose a change?

Comment: I didn't put in a new line character in my example as I thought putting the JSON in separate lines implied this.  I can change it, but I don't see why I should.  Maybe you can give me the cons before I change it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your file isn't a JSON document. Your file contains a series of JSON documents. To parse that, we can use the incremental parser from [`JSON::XS`](http://metacpan.org/module/JSON::XS) as follows:

```
use JSON::XS qw( );

my $file; { local $/; $file = <>; }

my $json = JSON::XS->utf8->new();
my @objs = $json->incr_parse($file);

@objs = sort { $a->{sequence_number} <=> $b->{sequence_number} } @objs;

for my $obj (@objs) {
   print($json->encode($obj), "\n");
}
```

If you assume that each line of the file is a separate and complete JSON document (which isn't guaranteed based on how you create them), you could use the following. But it doesn't really save you anything:

```
use JSON::XS qw( );

my $json = JSON::XS->utf8->new();

my @objs;
while (<>) {
   push @objs, $json->decode($_);
}

@objs = sort { $a->{sequence_number} <=> $b->{sequence_number} } @objs;

for my $obj (@objs) {
   print($json->encode($obj), "\n");
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks.  Ok, I guess I was lazy for not writing the double quotes and all in my example.  Yes, each line is valid JSON and I did include JSON::XS in my script just that failed to write it in my example.  Would you consider inserting a new line into the file and expect the result to be sorted a difficult task?

Comment: @Borodin, They're not in sequence, thus the question, and thus why I used "series" (*a number of things, events, or people of a similar kind or related nature coming one after another*) instead of "sequence". I had also deliberately chosen the order and thus the emphasis of my first two statements.

Comment: @Mark, I don't know why you mention quotes and loading JSON::XS. No, each line is not guaranteed to be valid JSON. (`encode_json` does not guarantee output without newlines.) As for your question, I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: Can we all just assume that this FILE contains a series of valid JSON each separated by a newline character?  I didn't put all the details in as I didn't want to write too long a post giving everyone a headache reading it.  If I were to provide the entire perl script here, no one would bother answering it as they would have to read through too many things.

Comment: @Borodin, this isn't consumed by a web service or anything like that so I don't see why it's a bad idea.  I'm crunching over a billion lines of log lines containing more than 12 formats. JSON works for me so I'm sticking with it.

Comment: Thank you @ikegami for your answer and as for my other question.....I'll probably re-ask it as another question.

Comment: @Mark, Re "Can we all just assume that this FILE contains a series of valid JSON each separated by a newline character?", You can assume anything you want. Is it safe to do so? Right now, I think so, but there's no guarantee that won't change. If you want to do that, I'd ask the JSON::XS author if he's willing to make such a guarantee. But as you can see from my answer, there's no reason to make such an assumption.